# Getx: what does the `.obs` function do?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

Could you explain what does the `.obs` function do?

```
RxInt _questionNumber = 1.obs;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes `questionNumber` an observable variable. Which means that whenever the value of that variable changes, that change will be automatically reflected on all places where it's being used.
It's like listening to a stream.

Answer (score 0):

it makes the value observable from anywhere in the app

Answer (score 0):

it means your _questionNumber variable is now observable variable. for show this variable data just wrap Print(_questionNumber.value) in Obx. it will be helpful.